# On what circumstances should we NOT use php inside javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
 $('#tip2').qtip({
   content: {
     text: '<?php echo "I do work."?>'
  },
```

In this case I'm using a jquery plugin but that doesn't matter for the question I believe.

I thought I had to go trough json calls (or other ajax call methods) because php runs first, and only later runs javascript, but, I actually tested this code, and it actually displays the text.

Can anyone please take some words to explain, on what circumstances should we NOT use php inside javascript. Is this one of them? If so, why?

I'm clearly not getting some client side, and server side workflow... please forgive my *newbielity* towards those matters.

Sorry if this was an inconvenient question.

**Update**

Please note that I'm asking about facts. Not opinions.
Someone states:
"You **shouldn't** do that way."

I'm asking:
"What facts (not opinions) sustain that claim?"

Comment: You cant mix them like this, PHP is server side code and runs on server, JS is client side is running inside clients browsers. Your code produces in your html text "echo "I do work"" becasue <?php ?> are not displayed by browser

Comment: If you absolutely *have* to get the PHP values inside your JS, I'd look into using `data` attributes. Unfortunately, printing content using PHP will mean that you can't easily uncouple everything.

Comment: @dafyk You absolutely can, as long as you want the outputted javascript to be `text: 'I do work.'`

Comment: @dafyk I don't understand, I cannot mix them, because one runs on server side and another on the client side... My question is: "Why can't we mix code that runs on the server side, with code that runs on the client side?" - by specifically look into this example.

Comment: You can anytime you want.  Just don't make a mess of your JS when you do.  If you are passing data, use `json_encode()`.  If you are doing something like minifying your script, be sure to cache the result.

Comment: @Brad I see a lot of do that, and do like this, and don't do like this. But my question is more about, the why. Why should or shouldn't we do it? Obviously by taking this small example into consideration. I mean, I do understand that running a lot of js code with a lot of php variables may not be the best way to split client and server side code, hence, bad maintenance and so on... but for those specific small cases, what is the main issue?

Comment: @MEM because your code wil not run, you can run PHP side of code on server, and JS in client (mostly browser). Browser doesnt have php code interpreters and browser only sees text in between < >, you can test it by echoing some $variable which will display "echo $variable" not content of $variable

Comment: @dafyk "JS in client (*mostly* browser)" Hmmm... Where else other than the browser would you see JS running on the client? And the PHP code *will* run if everything is working correctly, the browser should *not* see `<?php echo ... ?>` but rather the actual output.

Comment: @dafyk the code on the question, DOES work.

Comment: then thats kind of miracle for me, i cant understand how the php code is interpreted and by who.
@NullUserException nodejs on android for example

Comment: @MEM And then a few months later the code is littered with these "small specific cases."

Comment: @dafyk When did web pages on Android start running on anything but the browser? Node.js isn't even installed on Android by default. PHP is interpreted on the server.

Comment: @dafyk, Your confusion is that the PHP is somehow being executed client-side.  In fact, you are generating JavaScript with PHP.

Comment: @BenM, That's an absolutely terrible idea.  Just use `json_encode()` and you don't have to juggle types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be sensible to externalise most, if not all, of your JavaScript to another, static file for caching reasons.

It is possible to have a PHP file generate JavaScript, but as all dynamic content, it can not cache as well (while you can set-up caching headers, changes to the generated content will not be immediate, so you'll be forced to find a compromise between content accuracy and bandwidth savings).

I would externalise your example as so:

```
$('#tip2').qtip({
    content: {
     text: my_var
  },
```

Then create the following `<script>` block in your dynamic file before linking the static one:

```
my_var = '<?php echo 'I do work'; ?>';
```

This way, the vast majority of your JavaScript will be static, and eligible for Max-Age caching.

To provide you with a real-world example, I have recently implemented a pure JS plotting library that draws discrete data onto a canvas. The data to be plotted is supplied by the CGI (I didn't use PHP, but it shouldn't matter), so I used this approach to declare an array of values in the dynamic file, while externalising the actual handling and drawing code. It works beautifully, uses minimum bandwidth due to caching nicely, and is still very maintainable.

Unlike some other answers, I won't say you should avoid mixing server-side code with client-side; hell, HTML is client-side code that you are generating server-side. Depending on your needs, mixing JS and CGI can extend your possibilities, and applying my caching trick, there is no real downside.

Comment: Can you please explain me a little bit more about what cache issue are we talking here. Is it really a hit?

Comment: Basically, if you externalise your JavaScript and properly cache it (max-age, no-revalidate), it will only be downloaded once by the visitor, at the expense of a one-time extra HTTP request. Once they have the file cached, their browsers will no longer request it, saving you precious bandwidth, and even more importantly, improving loading speed.

Comment: So, it's not a big performance hit, we are not talking about seconds on loading pages but, really tiny micro seconds differences. However, when we multiply that for a lot of pages or, on really big web applications, that could play a role on the overall performance of all this, and THAT could be a problem?

Comment: Unless you bog down your site with massive amounts of data, or making that data do intensive client-side computation, the difference is never more than a few microseconds. Most webmasters I know are obsessive about trimming every needless byte by packing JS, creating heavily optimised CSS sprites of every single image on the site, etc. Consider it **good practice**.

Comment: Go it. Thanks for taking your time towards this. As far as I can tell, I will hardly get to obsessive over those small issues, when we, also often, disregard other decisions like: server host location and database optimization... :) (oh well).

Comment: I still have to read more about what max-age and no-revalidate means. ;)

Comment: I have updated my answer to give you an additional example and a short summary, I hope you find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A php file is interpreted by the web server and converted to a pure html file. That html file is then passed to the client's browser, which displays it.

In your case, the php echo is rendered as a string in the html page.

Keep in mind that if you do what you did in your example, the values rendered to the page are the values that exist *when the page is rendered by php*.

Comment: I'm aware of that, and I don't see a problem, on this case, about the fact that the rendered page values are the ones that do exist when the page is rendered by php. Since this is the case, what could the issue be?

Comment: Are you asking about whether you **should** do this, or whether you **can**? Because as far as technical limitations, there's nothing wrong with your example. It should work fine. Whether you **should** do that depends on the situation.

Comment: Indeed my question was about facts. (hence +1 for that). But facts that sustain the argument: "why shouldn't we do it like this?" - You seem to present one: "values rendered to the page are the values that exist when the page is rendered by php" (and that could be an issue so pay attention).

Comment: In that case, yes, you can do what you have posted. And as long as you understand that the server renders the php file as an html document, and that html document is what is passed to the client, you should understand the restrictions on interaction and what the limitations are.

Answer (score -3):

You should try not to use it as much as possible. However, there might be some very rare cases when you do need to pass values from your PHP code (say from a $_SESSION array) into your jQuery/JavaScript functions. In that case, if you don't have any other option then you can pass values like you did above. But in all other cases, try not to do it as much as possible since it is not a good practice. When you are combining 2 different languages like this, there might be cases when you get unpredictable behavior from the application/web-page.

Comment: You fail to say why you think it's not good practice.  There are certainly reasons why you may want all of your JS output by PHP, and it can be good practice depending on the situation.

Comment: Do you have any comments/suggestions to improve my answer?

Comment: It looks like he just gave you a commment or suggestion...